# Valorant HWID Band

Tags: riot-games-api, hwid

I have a HWID Ban in Valorant (Van 152) I used several spoofer like Woofer or InvisionCheats or Cheat City Spoofer (all paid ones) and flashed Bios afterwords. I even reinstalled Windoows and Valorant/Riot Games/Vanguard several times. I need help. Nothing seems to work to solve VAN 152 on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you cheated and therefore broke the ToS and by doing that likely made the experience for actual legitimate players worse I'd say tough luck especially considering this has nothing to do with SO